# On clicking CancelBtn cancel changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have in my program custom property grid, where all properties are bindable from viewModel. In this property grid there are also 2 buttons - SaveBtn and EditBtn. **User edit properties in property grid**. When SaveBtn is clicked, all properties must be saved in a database. If user wants to edit properties, he clicks EditBtn and then before saving properties to database(SaveBtn is clicked), should appear new window, where user chooses a reason of modification of a properties. On that window there are also three buttons - ExitWithSavingToDatabase, ExitWithoutSavingToDatabase and Cancel.

If user chooses Cancel, all changes should be canceled. But properties in viewModel already have new values. *My question is - how can I reset properties to old values???*  I was thinking of reloading properties from database, but if there is a better solution, where I can do it without using database?

Comment: You're working in reverse, you should be setting properties to new values if you click ok (or similar)

Comment: you can store your form using jscript and restore on btncancel click from jscript only.

Comment: @Sayse user should be able to edit properties in property grid. So when user hits editBtn, that he can edit properties, or I should create sort of popup form for editing values?

Comment: @Sasha - See Dennis' 3rd suggestion in his answer

Comment: Besides the view model object that changes on user input there may also be a related *model* object (the first M in MVVM), which would only change on Commit or Save. On Cancel you would simply reset the view model object from the model object (the data access object in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of approaches:

1. One of the you've mentioned - just throw away modified object and get new one with unchanged properties from store.
2. [Memento/Caretaker pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern). Memento is an object, that takes the snapshot of original values, and Caretaker is an object, that can rollback changes, using snapshot, stored in Memento (also, you may consider Undo/Redo as an evolution of this pattern).
3. You could modify a copy of object, and if the user wants to save changes, you should apply property values from copy to original. This requires object-to-object mappers (e.g. Automapper), as the manual copying of property values is error prone.

Answer (score 2):

A probably better way to go is to use only the values from the binding group, not the model.
This supports binding transaction commit/abort
Define a binding group for your window

```
  <Window.BindingGroup>
    <BindingGroup >
      <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
        <local:YourValidationClass/>
      </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
    </BindingGroup>
  </Window.BindingGroup>
```

YourValidationClass should handle the validation of a BindingGroup, not a single value. Important always use GetValue from the BindingGroup here, not from the Model, the Model is not modified yet

```
public class YourValidationClass : ValidationRule
  {
      public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
      {
          BindingGroup bindingGroup = (BindingGroup)value;

          if (bindingGroup.Items.Count == 1)
          {
              User user = (User)bindingGroup.Items[0];
              string firstName = (string)bindingGroup.GetValue(user, "FirstName");
              string lastName = (string)bindingGroup.GetValue(user, "LastName");

              if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
              {
                  return new ValidationResult(false, "Both fields required");
              }
          }
          return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
      }
  }
```

Your cancel button should then execute the following code:

```
this.BindingGroup.CancelEdit();
```

Your Save button should at least do

```
this.BindingGroup.CommitEdit();
```

to bind the group values to the model.

Comment: I believe that you don't even need any actual validations. You can essentially have an empty `<BindingGroup />` definition and just use it for the commit / cancel capabilities.;

Comment: this was an exceptionally simple solution, BTW thanks